# Issue with Sound Configuration in Ubuntu Docker Container on Google Cloud

Tags: sound, docker, cloud, google, container

I'm currently experiencing issues configuring sound within a Docker container on Google Cloud. I'm attempting to run a containerized environment with sound capabilities using the snd-aloop kernel module but encountering difficulties.

Here are the steps I've taken:

- Installed `snd-aloop` kernel module on the Google Cloud virtual machine instance.
- Ran the Docker container using the following command:

  ```
  docker run -it --rm --privileged -p 6080:80 -e ALSADEV=hw:2,0 dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc
  ```
- Tried to access /dev/snd directory within the container, but it appears to be missing.

However, despite specifying the necessary configurations, I keep getting errors related to /dev/snd not being available within the Docker container. I'm trying to use sound in the container for [mention the specific use case, e.g., multimedia applications, video playback, etc.].

Could you please provide guidance on:

- How to properly configure sound within a Docker container on Google Cloud using snd-aloop or any alternate methods?
- Any specific Google Cloud configurations or permissions needed to access sound devices from within the container?
- Whether there are known limitations or constraints regarding sound support in Docker containers on Google Cloud?

Comment: have you asked this question in the right place? How does this relate to ask ubuntu?